# iOS 6 iAd strange warning

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, iad, adbannerview

I have implemented iAd in my iPhone application. I am using storyboard and have two viewControllers. I have implemented an AdBannerView in both viewControllers and have set the delegate to self. I have imported the  and implemented the AdBanner delegate . I have also implemented the two methods `-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error` and `-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner` which hides and shows the adView depending on if there are any ads available. But when I run the app and switches back and forth between the two viewControllers about 10 times I get this printed in logger in Xcode. I also set the `adView = nil` in the `-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated` method

`WARNING: More than 10 instances of ADBannerView or ADInterstitialView currently exist. This is a misuse of the iAd API, and ad performance will suffer as a result. This message is printed only once.`

What does this mean? Have I done something wrong when I implemented iAd? Does this mean my app will be rejected by Apple?

**SOLVED:**

`[adView removeFromSuperview];` in the `-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated` method did it!

Comment: did u remove ADBannerView when navigate to another ViewController ??

Comment: Check that you're only creating one instance of the iAd view when your view loads, and only hiding and showing it in those delegate methods, not removing and recreating...

Comment: Developer.iOS I have set the adView = nil is the viewDidUnload method if that was what you ment?

Comment: jjv360 What do you mean by that? I'm I getting the whole concept of implementing iAd in the different viewControllers? should I do it another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, I think your problem solve

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
[_adView removeFromSuperview];
_adView.delegate = nil;
_adView = nil;
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks you! This have been driving me crazy for some hours now!

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you have more than 10 banner views in your app. Usually this occurs because of improper handling of the ads in a navigation controller scenario. You need to use a singleton instance of the banner view.

Google `uibannerview single instance`.